# element's height manipulation

Tags: jquery, css

As you know manipulating the height from 0 to auto using transition doesn't give the effect that we want and using max-height doesn't do the trick either, so I tried it with jquery and I made the transition from  height 0 to auto when I click, can you help me to get the height to 0 when I click again.

```
HTML
<ul>
 <li>Misión
    <p>Superar las necesidades más sofisticadas 
    apasionándonos la gestión de la complejidad.
    Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma</p>
 </li>   
 <li>Tecnologia
   <p>Superar las necesidades más sofisticadas 
   apasionándonos la gestión de la complejidad.
   Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma
   Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma</p>
 </li>   
</ul>

CSS
ul li {
   padding: 10px;
   font-weight: 700;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
   height: 40px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.7s;
}

ul li p {
   padding-top: 10px;
   line-height: 1.8;
   color: grey;
   font-weight: 100;
}

jQUERY
$("ul li").click(function() {
        var pHeight = $(this).find("p").height();
        $(this).height(pHeight);    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  if ($(this).get(0).style.height) {
    $(this).height('');
  } else {
    var pHeight = $(this).find("p").height();
    $(this).height(pHeight);
  }

});
```

```css
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

ul li p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Misión
    <p>Superar las necesidades más sofisticadas apasionándonos la gestión de la complejidad. Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma</p>
  </li>
  <li>Tecnologia
    <p>Superar las necesidades más sofisticadas apasionándonos la gestión de la complejidad. Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma Ser especialistas en combinar en una misma</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm. can you please explain this line of code  ($(this).get(0).style.height) what's the use of "get()"

Comment: Welcome. The call for $(this).get(0).style.height gets the inline style's height of the actual html element . If we make a call to the jquery css function, such as $(this).css('height'), it will compute the height and return a value regardless we set an inline style height or not.  An li element in your page does not have a specific height set to its inline style. When you call for $(this).height(pHeight);, it will set the height in its inline style to some value, let's say 57px. Hence, when we check next time for  $(this).get(0).style.height, it will return a value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would need to make the `li` a bit higher than the height of the `p`, or the content will not be entirely visible. E. g. adding the two heights:

```
$(this).height($(this).height() + pHeight)
```

Then, to reset the height, you can use

```
$(this).css('height', '')
```

This can also be used to remove any other CSS rules that you dynamically set via javascript or inline styles. External CSS rules will remain active.

Next, your way of hiding the `p` seems a bit hacky. I would hide it with `display: none` or `height: 0`. If you do this, you get the problem that `$(this).find("p").height()` will return `0`. So what you can do is set the height to `auto` for a nanosecond, measure the height and set it to `0` again immediately. In my experience you will never actually see this change. So after setting `height: 0` on `p`:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    var $p = $(this).find("p");
    $p.css('height', 'auto');
    var pHeight = $p.height();
    $p.css('height', '');
    $p.height(pHeight); 
});
```

Finally, for this task it may be easier to just use jquerys `slideToggle` function, though it may be less smooth than a CSS transition. After setting `display: none` on the `p`:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).find("p").slideToggle();
}
```